# Webpack not generating bundle since npm update

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, webpack

Some weeks ago I updated all my dependencies using `npm ... --force` and whatnot. Some may say this wasn't the greatest choice, but still...

I don't know exactly why, but since I updated my NPM dependencies, webpack doesn't generate my output bundle anymore, which it did before just fine.

The project is laid out as following

```
- app/
 |- dist/
 |- app-server/ (Node + Express)
   |- app.js
   |- ...
 |- app-frontend/ (Vue + Bootstrap)
   |- dist/ (HTML/CSS/etc)
```

webpack.config.js (Run from inside `app-server/`):

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = [
  {
    name: 'server',
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/../dist',
      filename: 'app_bundle.js',
    },
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    externals: [
      nodeExternals({})
    ],
    plugins: [
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [{ from: '../app-frontend/dist', to: '../dist/frontend' }],
      })
    ],
    stats: {
      colors: true,
      hash: false,
      version: false,
      timings: false,
      assets: false,
      chunks: false,
      modules: false,
      reasons: false,
      children: false,
      source: false,
      errors: false,
      errorDetails: false,
      warnings: false,
      publicPath: false,
    },
  },
];
```

The logs only say:

```
Entrypoints:
  app (434 KiB)
      css/chunk-vendors.f6f30965.css
      js/chunk-vendors.98eb6b3c.js
      css/app.a6ef7e2c.css
      js/app.4fd07954.js


Child server:
    Built at: 06.10.2020 19:07:17
    Entrypoint main = app_bundle.js
```

and no file gets generated. I tried `chmod 775 dist/` to no avail. I re-cloned the repo, to no avail. I deleted the CopyPlugin part, to no avail.
Hey, I even got to the root directory of my Ubuntu and did `find * | app_bundle.js -r` and it didn't find anything besides logs that have this name in it, which upon opening, are the log presented above.

I'm scratching my head on this since yesterday.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out!

The problem was that I was shooting myself in the foot by adding these lines:

```
stats: {
  errors: false,
  errorDetails: false,
  warnings: false,
}
```

Which basically meant that it just exited with error code 1, but without *telling me* the error.

I thought that these parameters were to disable the errors *within* the browser. Apparently *I was wrong*.

Once I set those above to `true` and running `webpack` again, I saw that it indeed had some errors.

***In my case***, the error was that I was creating files (under Windows) with the name (for example) `orderController.js`, but `require` them calling `../../OrderController`, which is, as you may see, not exactly equal. My file has a `o` and the script contains a capital `O`, which under Windows worked just fine, but I forgot that Linux (the server the production runs on) is **case-sensitive**.

After fixing those errors, `webpack` ran just fine and generated my bundle at the specified output directory!